# Unable to run php mysqli script from ubuntuserver

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I got hosted ubuntu server where I got apache2 and phpmyadmin. I wrote small script to connect to my mysql database. I placed that script in **/var/www/html/** . When I enter to 193.219.91.103:5858/init.php I just see blank page. I use php 7. I found that I could check if mysqli enabled with *php -m | grep mysql* it did showed me mysqli.

```
<?php
$db_name = "AndroidDatabase";
$mysql_user = "dbreader";
$mysql_pass = "dbreader";
$server_name = "localhost";
$port = 3306


$con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name,$port);
if(!$con)
{
        echo "Connection error".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
        echo "<h3>Database connection success</h3>";
}
?>
```

EDIT:
Fixed  all i missed was extra argument $port

Comment: If MySQL is on 193.219.91.103:5858, then Apache2 cannot be on 193.219.91.103:5858, so no way you can access 193.219.91.103:5858/init.php.  http://193.219.91.103/init.php is a possibility.    5858 is an unusual port number for MySQL.

Comment: that ports is because I use TCP forwarding. For example i can reach http://193.219.91.103:5858/phpmyadmin with no problems

Comment: Is is a typo in your question or in your code? `"AndroidDatabase:` should be `"AndroidDatabase"`.

Comment: @Syscall that was actually only pasting fail, fixed that